# Inductive Proof of String Reversal

Tags: logic

I am trying to inductively prove that for any string s, the reverse of the reverse of string s is string s.

Comment: I am sorry to hear that, because that sounds like a heavy-handed approach to something which is really obvious: the reverse of $a_1 \cdots a_n$ is $a_n \cdots a_1$ and the reverse of *that* is of course $a_1 \cdots a_n$.  Note though that you have not asked a question.

Comment: It could be to help familiarize the OP with induction.

Comment: What is your inductive definition of "string reversal" ?

Answer (score 6):

The case $n = 1$ is trivial. For $n > 1$, assume that the statement holds for all $i < n$.
Let $s = as'$ be a string of length $n$ where $a$ has length 1 and $s'$ has length $n - 1$. The key is to observe that rev($ab$) = rev($b$)rev($a$). Therefore rev(rev($s$)) = rev(rev($as'$)) = rev(rev($s'$)rev($a$)) = rev(rev($a$))rev(rev($s'$)) = $as'$ = $s$, thus the statement holds for strings of length $n$. We have now proved by induction that the reverse of the reverse of a string $s$ is $s$.